# css dynamically overlaid <divs> with mouse-over opacity

Tags: html, css

We are trying to get our new company-team page up and running. What we are trying to accomplish is to have employee images in `<divs>` so they resize dynamically, and then on mouse over have the image dimmed and the employee bio visible. Something similar to the employee mouseover found here: http://studiompls.com/about/

What has been cobbled together that sort of works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

div.gallery {
    position:relative;
     background: #6E6E6E;
     color: #fff; 
     font-weight:bold;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;


}

div.gallery:hover {
   opacity: .6;
       -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
       -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
       transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;

}

div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}



div.desc {
   position: relative;
         top: 50%;
         transform: translateY(-50%);
         vertical-align:middle;

}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
    padding: 0 6px;
    float: left;
    width: 24.99999%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:relative;


}
.responsive:hover{

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .responsive {
        width: 49.99999%;
        margin: 6px 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .responsive {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.wrapper{

     position:relative;
     background: #6E6E6E;
     color: #fff; 
     font-weight:bold;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper:hover{
    opacity: .6;
       -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
       -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
       transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="responsive">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="gallery">
      <img src="images/Gary.jpeg" alt="" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
  </div>
   </div>
<div class="responsive">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="gallery">
      <img src="images/Andy.jpeg" alt="" width="300" height="200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="gallery">
      <img src="images/Chris.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="responsive">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="gallery">
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div style="padding:6px;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The overlaid `<div>`s do no stay lined up, and if we add text to the background `<div>` it separates them further. Anyone see what's missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this HTML and CSS

**Extra CSS**

```
 .container {
position: relative;

}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
background-color: black;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

**UPdated HTML**

```
<div class="gallery container">
    <img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" width="300" height="200">
    <div class="middle">
       <div class="text">John Doe</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_opacity

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container1 {
   display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 div.gallery {
     position:relative;
     background: #6E6E6E;
     color: #fff; 
     font-weight:bold;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     }
     div.gallery:hover {
     -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     }
     div.gallery img {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     }
     div.desc {
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     vertical-align:middle;
     }
     * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     }
     .responsive {
     padding: 0 6px;
     width:33.3%;;
     vertical-align:middle;
     position:relative;
     }

     @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
     .responsive {
     width: 49.9%;
     margin: 6px 0;
     }
     }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
     .responsive {
     width: 100%;
     }
     }
     .clearfix:after {
     content: "";
     display: table;
     clear: both;
     }
     .wrapper{
     position:relative;
     background: #6E6E6E;
     color: #fff; 
     font-weight:bold;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     }
     .wrapper:hover{
     -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
     }
     
     
.container {
position: relative;

}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
background-color: black;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


   <body>
 <div class="container1">
  <div class="responsive">
     <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="gallery container">
           <img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" width="300" height="200">
           <div class="middle">
                <div class="text">John Doe</div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
     <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="gallery container">
           <img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" width="300" height="200">
           <div class="middle">
                <div class="text">John Doe</div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
     <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="gallery container">
           <img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" width="300" height="200">
           <div class="middle">
                <div class="text">John Doe</div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="responsive">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="gallery">
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div style="padding:6px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is a bit closer; how can we a) get the text box to be the same size as the image and b) get the images to lay out in a sort of table format IE 3 across?

Comment: '<div class="text">` : looking to have the text box either overlay the image completely or be positioned such that the text would start at the top center of the image, and the wen the image grays out the only thing you would see is the text overlaying the image. Also we don't want to have the text grayed out at all. That should be full opacity.

Comment: that's it. So we needed one more `<div>` to wrap everything in. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: if I am understanding this layout in order to add some whitespace around each image changing the padding in `.responsive` would the best approach correct?